# on pagebeforeshow need to check the checkbox using name and value in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

Hi on pagebeforeshow need to check the checkbox using name and value in jquery mobile, is it possible? Can someone help me please? Thanks. I have tried but am not able to get so.

```js
$('input:checkbox[name=checkbox-v-1][value="Patient"]').prop("checked",true);
```

```html
<div id="chkboxdiv">
   <fieldset id="CG-demo" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-vertical ui-corner-all" data-role="controlgroup">
      <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="checkbox-v-10">Patient</label>
        <input id="checkbox-v-10" type="checkbox" value="Patient" name="checkbox-v-1" checked="checked">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="checkbox-v-11">Clinician</label>
        <input id="checkbox-v-11" type="checkbox" value="Clinician" name="checkbox-v-1" checked="checked">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="checkbox-v-12">PayTM Customer</label>
        <input id="checkbox-v-12" type="checkbox" customer="" value="PayTM" name="checkbox-v-1" checked="checked">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="checkbox-v-13">CClass</label>
        <input id="checkbox-v-13" type="checkbox" value="CClass" name="checkbox-v-1" checked="checked">
      </div>
      <div class="ui-checkbox">
        <label class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off" for="checkbox-v-14">BClass</label>
        <input id="checkbox-v-14" type="checkbox" value="BClass" name="checkbox-v-1" checked="checked">
      </div>
```

Comment: Please provide your markup.

Comment: markup in the sense?

Comment: $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() { } using this am able to get the unchecked values can i make them checked

Comment: given as $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
             alert($(this).attr("id"));
             //$(this).prop("checked",true);
             var id = $(this).attr("id");
             document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
             
       })
but it didn't check the checkboxes

Comment: Are you using jQM 1.4? and what do you want to achieve exactly? retrieve values of checked checkboxes?

Comment: yes, i have to check the value with selected checkboxes earlier, again moving to that page i have to make them as default selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty much there on your first attempt.

When setting the checked property, set it to checked instead of true:  `.prop("checked", "checked")`

After setting the checked property, refresh the jQM widget: `.checkboxradio("refresh")`

So now the whole line is

```
$('input:checkbox[name="checkbox-v-1"][value="Patient"]').prop("checked", "checked").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/u4Lsu4au/)**

Click the page2 button and see that patient is checked.